# Использование IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

Возможно ли на платформе Windows Phone 8 использование `IsolatedStorageSettings` фоновым агентом аудио? Я пытался создать `IsolatedStorageSettings` в основном приложении и использовать его фоновым агентом, но ничего не понятно, то ли использует агент объявленные настройки, то ли нет. В некоторых случаях работает правильно, а иногда глючит, подозреваю, что агент затирает созданный файл настроек, может кто знает?

Comment: Может быть, логгинг поможет узнать, что происходит? (У меня, к сожалению, нету опыта по этой теме для более полезного ответа.)

Comment: Вообщем, намудохался с опытами и пришел к выводу (для себя), что не было предусмотрено нашими "богами" (майками) чтобы 'IsolatedStorageSettings' корректно работал с двумя процессами и, поэтому, я создал костыль из 'IsolatedStorageFile', который имитирует работу вышеупомянутого функционала. Но спасибо за совет :)

Comment: @RomanNomokonov разместите свой комментарий как ответ и отметье его правильным. Плюс: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20969958/1985167

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообщем, намудохался с опытами и пришел к выводу (для себя), что не было предусмотрено нашими "богами" (майками) чтобы 'IsolatedStorageSettings' корректно работал с двумя процессами и, поэтому, я создал костыль из 'IsolatedStorageFile', который имитирует работу вышеупомянутого функционала